# Add My App Function to Contact Screen (as in WhatsApp)

Tags: android

Want to add my Android app icon to a contact screen (in the regular contacts display), so when a user checks out the contact he / she can press it to automatically start the function for that user.

A good example of this practice is WhatsApp, which adds its icon to a contact so you can press it and immediately start messaging a user (if there's a WhatsApp account associated with it).

Does anyone know how to use the API to do this?

Comment: Any success on this?

Comment: Nope. Stopped working on the project. Still interesting though